SwiftUI infinite ScrollView performance when adding new children while scrolling
I've implemented an infinite scroll in SwiftUI based on this article, which works great in general terms, but I'm experiencing a small performance issue that is driving me nuts.
My app features a vertical List with an infinite ScrollView feed per row. I've noticed that there's a small performance issue when appending new items from a new page request, at first I was blaming to a potential expensive rerender, but I simplified my main view to a single row, rendering plain rectangles and I'm still seeing subtle "leaps" on every rerender, as illustrated in the image.-

It might not be very noticeable in the gif, but basically the scroll makes a small jump (like missing frames), every time I add an item (in order to simplify, I'm currently adding just one item per page load, and just a simple rectangle instead of my real card view).
Here is the relevant code for my ScrollView:
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    LazyHStack(spacing: 10) {
        ForEach((0...fetcher.lastIndexToShow(section)), id: \.self) { index in
            ZStack {
                if let item = fetcher.items[section]?[safe: index] {
                    if index < 30 {
                        ItemCard(item: item)
                    } else {
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 400, height: 220)
                            .opacity(1)
                            .padding(10)
                        }
                    } else {
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 400, height: 220)
                            .opacity(0)
                            .padding(10)
                        }
                    }
                    .task {
                        try? fetcher.fetchNewPageIfNeeded(section: section, index: index)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The method fetchNewPageIfNeeded simply checks whether or not to load a new page based on the index, a threshold, and the total known amount of items, and if positive calls to fetchNextPage:
func fetchNextPage(section: String) throws {
    Task { @MainActor in
        guard let res: ApiResponse<Game> = try await fetch(url: url) else {
             return
        }
        if res.data.count > 0 {
            await MainActor.run {
                items[section]?.append(contentsOf: [res.data[0]])              
            }
        }
    }
}

fetcher is an ObservableObject and items is the only Published var I'm updating in the whole operation. And by the way, the capture is from visionOS simulator, but I'm experiencing the same issue on real iPad device.
Any idea pointing in the right direction for performance improvement, or what else could I check / simplify to understand the real source of the problem is much appreciated :)
